# Pronunciation of words ending in consonant in Senese Italian

Tags: regional, pronunciation

The term *Senese Italian* refers to the Italian language as spoken in and close to Siena, Tuscany. When a word ends in consonant, Senese Italian speakers tend to geminate said consonant and to follow it with a schwa. Thus we have for eng. *bar* sen.it. *bar**rə***, for eng. *hotel* sen.it. *hotel**lə***, for eng. *pub* sen.it. *pab**bə*** etc.

I'm aware of the fact that the addition of [ə] is a case of paragoge, but how would one describe the gemination? Is there an order in the application of the two rules?

Comment: I don't know the answer, and personally I think that this question is somewhat off-topic in this website, which is basically about standard Italian. But I can add that something very similar happens in the Roman variety of Italian: *er busse* (the bus), *er gasse* (the gas) etc.

Comment: @DaG Probably we should discuss it in meta, but I think that regional Italian (as opposed to Italian dialects) should be fully on topic.

Comment: Not sure this is on topic either. Local dialects have little to do with standard Italian apart from a few exceptions. In many cases they are completely different languages.

Comment: @Gio: We are not talking about local dialects, but about [regional Italian](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1323/707). I had to study something about this last year when I was doing my C1 Italian course.

Comment: @Charo - Yes, I know what regional means here, but do you think the question  is about regional variants rather than local dialect. The fact that it refers to Siena  doesnt make it necessarily so.

Comment: Regional varieties of Italian are fascinating (and generally quite easily understandable, for what's worth). But the fact is that they involve a wholly different corpus of knowledge and reference works (if any) with respect to standard Italian. For instance, texts about standard Italian are generally available and it is studied and discussed all over the world, while its single regional varieties are often the topic of locally-published books and papers, sometimes verging on the amateurish.

Comment: The same happens elsewhere in Tuscany. *Il bar* is often pronounced *i' barrə* - or even *ibbarre* - in Florence, Pisa and Leghorn. Actually, *I* sometimes do so in informal contexts.

Comment: Absolutely! I chose Siena only because I know that there it is quite systematical, whereas in Florence, for example, you can hear both variants.

Comment: And regarding the 'off-topic' argument: My question can be answered without any formal knowledge of dialects or regional Italian. It has more to do with the *type* of a phonological process than with anything else.

Comment: @eslukas: I am not an expert in phonological phenomena, but my hunch is that it could fall within the “[raddoppiamento espressivo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento-espressivo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/)”, but I am ready to be refuted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from the region, but I think the gemination in these examples is natural for the speakers due to the standard rules of the raddoppiamento fonosintattico.
The tonic accent is always in the last syllable in your (and DaG's) examples, so the last letter (with its schwa) is somehow treated as an unstressed particle (like in dallo, fanne etc).
Would you observe the same phenomenon in words like compùter or bàncomat?

Comment: Nice. Why [raddoppiamento (fono)sintattico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento-sintattico_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) rather than [raddoppiamento espressivo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento-espressivo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/)?

Comment: @DaG I was just referring to the general rule of gemination after an oxytone. Indeed your definition sounds definitely linguistically more accurate in this case